# Java Design Patterns Quiz

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

Recently I came across a problem which I was asked to design using appropriate design patterns. The proble statement is:

```
Implement a remote control of TV. 
Any remote control we use, either at home/hotel or at a friend’s place, 
we just pick up the TV remote control and start pressing Up and Down 
or Forward and Back keys to change the channels.
Choose a suitable design pattern for implementation of this problem.
```

I am not able to figure out how to design this ask. This is what I came up with:

> Place is an abstract class.
>
> Home extends Place
>
> Hotel extends Place
>
> FriendPlace extends Place
>
> TVRemote is a class
>
> Place has a TVRemote
>
> Keys is an interface
>
> Keys has a method press()
>
> UpKey, DownKey, ForwardKey, BackKey are classes implementing Keys
>
> TVRemote has Keys
>
> There could be more Keys in TVRemote

This is what I could think of but unable to incorporate a Design Pattern here. Any guidance?

Comment: how would the design be like?

Comment: I think place is irrelevant, because the interaction between a TV and remote control is completely independent of the location.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach will be to create an interface

```
interface RemoteControl 
{
public void up(); 
public vois down();
public void forward();
public void back();
}
```

and then create specific classes that will implement  that interface for specific devices

e.g.

```
public class HomeRemote implements RemoteControl {

public void up(){
..
} 

public vois down(){
..
}

public void forward(){
..
}

public void back(){
..
}

}
```

**However**

After our discussion - and after searching a little bit more, i am inclined to think now that **Bridge** pattern is what is asked for here. 
Check this out - http://www.programcreek.com/2011/10/java-design-pattern-bridge/

There abstract class for remote control is used with basic implementation of (up,down,forward,back)
Then each specific TVRemote extends the abstract class to add more/and device specific functionality.

Also note that TVs are using common interface where (goUp(),goDown(),goForward(),goBack() and possibly on(),off()) functions are described.

Comment: How is home remote different than friend's place remote when all they have is 4 commands and interacting with the same device TV?

Comment: The devices are actually different -  if I have at home say LG  and you have Samsung or something - they are designed in totally different ways. 4 commands you are referring to are the common interface - but each device implements it differently (on the low level). The end  user doesn't care about actual implementation - he/she just uses the interface,

Comment: Right. End user need not to worry about the implementation but I feel all the commands have same functionality despite having to work with different model devices. Up key would perform up only and same with Down and forward and back. I suppose there isn't any need of separate Remote implementation. A Remote has a Key and when you press() UpKey, it performs operation.

Comment: O.K. so we disagree on that ;-) 'Up' can in fact be implemented in different ways - if you take into account what signal is received how it is processed internally etc - it is irrelevant that it 'feels' the same to the user.  So, it is quite clear to me that they are asking of you to use interfaces.  Also note that problem ask of you to Implement a remote control of TV. So I think describing in your answer places locations etc is irrelevant.

Comment: Place, I agree is irrelevant. We can discard it. About the commands functionality, Back and Forward are to change the channels and let say Up and Down are to change the volume. So functionality remains the same for all remotes.

Comment: @roger_that ok look at the second part of the answer - may be it is a bridge pattern after all.

Comment: what if you want to add a button to your remote? and what if some remotes have two buttons only, but others have four? change interface and make all implementations stop compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- different remote controls may have different number of buttons
- different buttons execute different actions
- remote control should be oblivious of the details how the action is executed
- one should be able to reprogram remote control either by assigning different actions to buttons or by supporting different devices

The most straightforward pattern to use with this situation is `Command`. One could create specific `Command` implementations and then assign `Command`s to buttons:

```
public interface Command {
    void Execute();
}
public class Button {
    private readonly Command command;
    public Button(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
    public void Press() {
        this.command.Execute();
    }
 }
 public class Remote {
     public Button ButtonPlaceholder1 { get; set; }
     public Button ButtonPlaceholder2 { get; set; }
     public Button ButtonPlaceholder3 { get; set; }
     public Button ButtonPlaceholder4 { get; set; }
 }
```

So, what would be the benefit of having `Button` class? Well, let's say you want to introduce a slider button, which can be moved Up and Down. In this case, you will configure it with two `Command`s:

```
public class SliderButton {
    public SliderButton(Command up, Command down) {
        this.commandUp = up;
        this.commandDown = down;
    }
    public void Up() {
        this.commandUp.Execute();
    }
    public void Down() {
        this.commandDown.Execute();
    }
}
```

And interesting follow-up question on this interview would be, "How to implement a button that would cancel the action made by pressing previous button? (e.g. I was watching ESPN channel, but there was a break in between a match, so I switched to MTV, but I want to check once in a while whether break has ended, and if not, go back to MTV)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern here.  Usually it has Invoker, Client, Command and Receiver. Here are the classes you may require.

**Command**

```
public interface ICommand {
    void execute();
}
```

**Invoker**

```
public class RemoteControl {
    Map<Key, ICommand> commandsByKey;

    public RemoteControl() {
        commandsByKey = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setCommand(Key key, ICommand command) {
        commandsByKey.put(key, command);
    }

    public void press(Key key) throws Exception {
        ICommand command = commandsByKey.get(key);
        if(command == null)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Key");
        command.execute();
    }
}
```

**Receiver**

```
public class TV {
    private String brand;

    public TV(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return brand + " TV";
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public abstract class Place {
    private TV tv;
    private RemoteControl remoteControl;

    public Place(TV tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
        this.remoteControl = new RemoteControl();

        remoteControl.setCommand(Key.UP, new UpCommand(this.tv));
        remoteControl.setCommand(Key.FORWARD, new ForwardCommand(this.tv));
        remoteControl.setCommand(Key.DOWN, new DownCommand(this.tv));
        remoteControl.setCommand(Key.BACK, new BackCommand(this.tv));
    }

    public TV getTv() {
        return tv;
    }

    public RemoteControl getRemoteControl() {
        return remoteControl;
    }
}

public class Home extends Place {
    public Home() {
        super(new TV("Sony"));
    }
}

public class Hotel extends Place {

    public Hotel() {
        super(new TV("LG"));
    }
}
```

**Concrete Commands**

```
public class UpCommand implements ICommand {
    private TV tv;

    public UpCommand(TV tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Up Command  - " + tv);
    }

}


public class DownCommand implements ICommand {
    private TV tv;

    public DownCommand(TV tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Down Command  - " + tv);
    }
}


public class ForwardCommand implements ICommand {
    private TV tv;

    public ForwardCommand(TV tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Forward Command  - " + tv);

    }

}


public class BackCommand implements ICommand {
    private TV tv;

    public BackCommand(TV tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Back Command  - " + tv);
    }

}
```

**Keys**

```
public enum Key {
    UP, DOWN, FORWARD, BACK
}
```

**TEST**

```
public class RemoteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Place home = new Home();
        home.getRemoteControl().press(Key.UP);
        home.getRemoteControl().press(Key.DOWN);
        home.getRemoteControl().press(Key.BACK);

        Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
        hotel.getRemoteControl().press(Key.UP);
    }
}
```

If you add any additional keys to the remote you don't need to touch any of the existing command or invoker. You just need to add it in the client. This adheres to [Open Close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). If you have different remote for each place then make it as constructor argument, so you no need to change any other classes.